# is there a way to refresh the state after each onClick event in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, express, react-redux

I am trying to obtain a list of json objects such as:

```
[ {yes: 1, no: 0, nil: 0},
 {yes: 0, no: 1, nil: 0}, 
{yes: 1, no: 0, nil: 0},
 {yes: 0, no: 1, nil: 0}].
```

at the moment however, once i click on any of the above it stays as 1, and eventually all becomes 1 which is not what i want:

```
[ {yes: 1, no: 0, nil: 0},
     {yes: 1, no: 1, nil: 0}, 
    {yes: 1, no: 1, nil:0 },
     {yes: 1, no: 1, nil: 1}]
```

for each click I want to push the state to a firebase database and later retrieve it from the app as a json object to plot a graph.

```
export default class Vote extends Component {
constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = {
     yes: 0,
     no: 0,
     nil: 0,
  };
  this.current = [];
};
handleClick = (e) => {
    const ref = baseDb
        .ref("votes")
        ref.push({
            dataset: this.state
        })
    this.setState({[e.target.name]: 1 })
    this.current.push(this.state) 
    console.log(this.current)    
}

<div className="form-group row">
                        <div>
                            <button  className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.handleClick}
                            name= "yes"
                            >
                            Yes
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.handleClick}
                            name= "no"
                            >
                            NO
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.handleClick}
                            name= "nil"
                            >
                            Undecided
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: You can just use `this.setState(<initial state>)`

Comment: i've tried this before, it didn't work!

Comment: What isn't working about this code? Is your UI not updating? Or is the data in the database not what you expect?

Comment: its the UI. for each click i want all the state values to go back to 0, but it's persisting as 1.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you want to happen in the question. Do you want to update firestore on click but reset the state with the same click? It's a little hard to grok, if you clarify and update your question with an example of what you want to happen it will be easier to help you.

Comment: that's exactly what i want! but it's not resetting the state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys for your contributions, I was able to use async and await to resolve the issue as follows:

```
export default class Vote extends Component {
constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = {
     yes: 0,
     no: 0,
     nil: 0,
  };
  this.current = [];
};

handleClick = async (e) => {

        await this.setState({[e.target.name]: 1 })

        const ref = baseDb
        .ref("dataset")
        ref.push({
            voter: this.state
        })
    this.current.push(this.state) 
    console.log(this.current) 
    this.setState({ yes: 0, no: 0, nil: 0 })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

State works in an async way, if you push your state to this.current after immediately setting the state, the state maybe wouldn't have been set at that time, would be better to make that push inside the componentDidUpdate hook, which will wait until the state is modified and the component rerendered

Comment: Although i've tried this before without success, I was just using the 'this.current' to check on the console. the goal was to push it straight to firebase as shown on the code.